# Remove any phrase in a list based on capitalization (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
   List
   Justin Bieber
   The hills
   George Clooney
   very good
   is a
```

Is there a fast way to filter this list so only bigrams where both words are uppercase are left?  Based on the example above, the new list would look like:

```
  List
  Justin Bieber
  George Clooney
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)?

```
>>> lst = ["Something", "This no", "This Yes", "not this"]
>>> list(filter(lambda s: all(x[0].isupper() for x in s.split()), lst))
['Something', 'This Yes']
```

With list comprehension it's pretty much the same:

```
>>> [s for s in lst if all(x[0].isupper() for x in s.split())]
['Something', 'This Yes']
```

You may want to set the number of words it matches, but your example didn't - so neither did I.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner (but not the fastest):

```
names = [s for s in str_list if len(s.split()) == 2 and all(word[0].isupper() for word in s.split())]
```